# Why have my storyboards become transparent?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, transparent

I'm sure I screwed something up here, but my storyboard backgrounds have all become transparent. Is there something I could have done to have done this accidentally? The color settings show that I have full opacity, so can anyone tell me why this is happening?  I've done nothing programmatically, regarding the background.  I'm using Xcode 6.3.1.

[image: storyboard background]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'storyboard backgrounds'? View controllers root views or XCode window when storyboard is selected? First case - check your view's alpha property. Second case - you can reduce window transparency on Yosemite in accessibility options.

Comment: Do they show up when you run your app?

Comment: I should have stated that alphas are all set to 1.0.  Also, the OS window transparency is normal, it's just the view controllers that have changed to transparent.  They render this way in the simulator as well.  Any other ideas?  I'm scratching my head.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Weird.

Comment: Not really, I'm pretty sure it's a bug.  By dropping the alpha to .99, the problem effectively resolves because the background becomes opaque again.  As soon as I change back to 1, it goes back to transparent.  Totally weird.  I've had to change the alpha on every VC, but at least it's no longer a functional issue.